# jQuery .animate() not working in Chrome (jumps to new starting position)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, jquery-animate

So, this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aXsWz/31/ actually works how I want things to work. However, that is not what happens with my actual code (cannot get Fiddle to replicate the issue yet). However, hopefully I can explain it thoroughly to get help. It works in Firefox and IE, just not in Chrome.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

$('div#navNavigate').click(function(){
        $('div#navNavigateHide').show()
        $('div#navNavigate').hide()
        $('div#sideNav').show()
        $('div#container').animate({'left':'+=120'});
    });  

$('div#navNavigateHide').click(function(){
        $('div#navNavigate').show()
        $('div#navNavigateHide').hide()
        $('div#container').animate({'left':'-=120'});
    });
});
```

Rather than the "container" div just moving over, it first jumps left to a new starting position and then animates by the specified distance. Also, I want to note that the jump is a larger distance than the specified animate distance (i.e. my container jumps nearly off screen and then animates back into partial view. If it jumped equal distance, it'd then animate back to it's original position).

I'll post more code / updated fiddle when I can replicate it, but if anyone can help until then it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT*** So the fiddle does NOT work when put into regular files and viewed in Chrome. There won't be a way to replicate it using jsfiddle, unfortunately. However, anyone willing to help and wants to see the issue, just copy paste the fiddle into three files and open up the html. You'll see the issue in action.

**EDIT*** I was just thinking... if it's just happening on my computer, then maybe it's my jQuery? I have 1.7.1 downloaded currently. So maybe I'll go grab the newest version. MAybe that'll work...

**EDIT*** FIXED! It was the jQuery version. Good to go now.

Comment: (Not related to your problem, but) Why `$('div#navNavigate')` and not `$('#navNavigate')`? When selecting by ID you don't need the tag name.

Comment: @jstacks I wouldn't necessarily consider it a bad habit. I've seen some online schools teach selectors with the leading tag... It's more about what you're comfortable with, or what your co-workers/team choose as a convention. That said, I never use the leading tag name.

Comment: It's not bad if it's done on purpose for a specific reason, but if it's done purely out of habit for no particular reason... Note that `'div#nav'` says "select the `#nav` element if it is a div", whereas `'#nav'` says "select the `#nav` element regardless of its type" - either of which could work to your advantage or to your disadvantage depending on context. Personally I don't like including the tag name because then in future if the markup changes the `<div>` to a `<td>` or `<p>` or whatever then the JS has to change too. (And, if it matters, no tag name performs better.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! Well, I downloaded the newest version of jQuery and now it works. Simple fix. Finally!

Comment: Seems weird that something that basic would be a jQuery version issue, but it's always nice to hear people being able to solve their own problems!  Good luck with the rest of the project

Answer (score -1):

try replacing

```
  $('div#container').animate({'left':'+=120'});
```

and

```
   $('div#container').animate({'left':'-=120'});
```

with

```
  $('div#container').stop().animate({'left':'+=120'});
```

and

```
  $('div#container').stop().animate({'left':'-=120'});
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you could consolidate your functions into one.  Sometimes this can help timing/sequencing issues.

Try this:

```
var hidden = true;
$('div#navNavigate').click(function(){
if (hidden) {    
    $('div#container').animate({'left':'+=120'});
} else {
    $('div#container').animate({'left':'-=120'});
}
    hidden = !hidden;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/PdHFJ/)   ​